# Como adicionar múltiplos Runs em um parágrafo com uma parte da string em bold no WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

Boa tarde,

Sou completamente nova em WPF, me perdoem se a pergunta for imbecil.
Preciso formatar duas strings que estejam contidas no mesmo parágrafo, sendo uma em negrito, e a outra em texto normal.

Eu fiz da seguinte forma:

```
    Bold sting1 = new Bold(new Run(string.Format("{0}:", item.Chave))); // primeira parte

    Run string2= new Run(string.Format("\t{0}", item.Valor)); // segunda parte

    p1 = new Paragraph(string1).Inlines.Add(string2);// p1 já foi declarado como Block em outra parte do código
```

Fazendo isso, recebo o seguinte erro:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type void to
>   System.Windows.Documents.Block"

Agradeceria se alguém tivesse uma luz.
Agradeço muito a atenção.

Comment: Tá adicionando essas strings aonde?

Comment: Adiciono ao final em: flowDoc.Document.Blocks.Add(p1); Mas já consegui aqui. Agradeço muito a sua ajuda. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver. Ao invés de:

```
Bold sting1 = new Bold(new Run(string.Format("{0}:", item.Chave))); 
Run string2= new Run(string.Format("\t{0}", item.Valor));
p1 = new Paragraph(string1).Inlines.Add(string2);
```

Usei o seguinte código:

```
p1 = new Paragraph();
(p1 as Paragraph).Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run(item.Chave + ":\t")));
(p1 as Paragraph).Inlines.Add(new Run(item.Valor));
```